# Operator like " >>,<<" overloading does not work

Tags: c++

Here is My Code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Complex
{
private:
    double re;
    double im;
public:
    Complex(double x=0,double y=0):re(x),im(y){}
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&os,const Complex&a);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream &is,const Complex&a);
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream&os,const Complex&a)
{
    os<<"a"<<a.re<<"+j"<<a.im<<endl;
    return os;
}
istream& operator>>(istream&is,const Complex&a)
{
    is>>a.re>>a.im;
    return is;
}
int main()
{
    Complex d;
    cout<<"enter the value of object";
    cin>>d;
    cout<<"value is"<<d;
    return 0;
}
```

When i execute program runs and stop automaticaly
It gives the following as output

Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)   execution time : 3.066 s
Press any key to continue.

Comment: How are you even changing a `const` object via `>>`?

Comment: you cannot read to a `const Complex&`, interesting question is: Why does this compile?

Comment: @ArdentCoder I didn't believe it either, but no errrors/warnings: https://wandbox.org/permlink/BoCNp5NrwIvfGSJp

Comment: what should i do please help

Comment: @idclev463035818 Wow, I'm upvoting this question

Comment: warning of clang explains why it compiles... infinite recursion with `is>>a.re`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary problem is that you made the second parameter of `operator>>` `const`. A `const` reference cannot be used to modify the object, but `operator>>` should do that.

Now, the question is, why does it compile at all? The expectation would be that there is no viable overload of `operator>>` that takes a `const double&` (the type of `a.re` and `a.im` in your `operator>>` overload) as second argument. There is only a `double&` overload in the standard library. So how does `is>>a.re>>a.im;` not cause a compilation failure?

That is because you made the constructor of `Complex` non-`explicit` and callable with exactly one argument of type `double`.

Therefore each `>>` in

```
is>>a.re>>a.im;
```

will actually call your `operator>>` overload again, by doing a user-defined conversion of the `a.re` or `a.im` argument from `double` to `Complex`, using the mentioned non-`explicit` constructor and that `Complex` can bind to the `const` reference of `operator>>` again.

You should make constructors that can be called with exactly one argument `explicit` by default if you don't have any specific reason to do otherwise, to avoid such issues. The `explicit` keyword forbids the constructor from being used in implicit conversion sequences as above, which are often surprising and unintentionally.

So effectively you have an infinite recursion in `operator>>` (and your compiler may tell you about this if you enable warnings). This causes undefined behavior in theory and a stack overflow causing a segmentation fault in practice.

Comment: scary how a small typo can have bad effects. I didn't update my list of reasons against implicit conversions since a while because it was just too long, but this one should go somewhere on the top. Even reading the warning I didn't get what is going on here

Comment: @idclev463035818 Now C++ haters have another reason

Comment: @ArdentCoder they will always find reasons, no matter what

Answer (score 1):

OK the problem with above code is that i used >> operator on const object so the actual code goes like

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Complex
{
private:
    double re;
    double im;
public:
    Complex(double x=0,double y=0):re(x),im(y){}
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&os,const Complex&a);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream &is,Complex&a);
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream&os,const Complex&a)
{
    os<<"a"<<a.re<<"+j"<<a.im<<endl;
    return os;
}
istream& operator>>(istream&is,Complex&a)//here was the error
{
    is>>a.re>>a.im;
    return is;
}
int main()
{
    Complex d;
    cout<<"enter the value of object";
    cin>>d;
    cout<<"value is"<<d;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is just a solution that fixed your problem, which was simply a typo. But did you know the reason why your original code did not work? You should tick the answer which explained that.

Comment: @ArdentCoder can you please explain like you are explaining it to a beginner

Comment: I'm finding it hard to explain that in simple words. You can comment it below that answer and hope its author will help you understand that.